# Proof by Contradiction: Prove that there are no solutions x and y to the equation 3$x^2$ - 5$y^2$ = 19. (Hint: consider this equation modulo 5)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]Proof by Contradiction: Prove there is no $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 3$x^2$ - 5$y^2$ = 19. (Hint: consider this equation modulo 5)

$\neg$P: There ARE solutions in integers x and y to the equation 3$x^2$ - 5$y^2$ = 19.

For the sum to be odd, the two components must be in two cases.

### Case 1:

3$x^2$ is even, and 5$y^2$ is odd.

### Case 2:

3$x^2$ is odd, and 5$y^2$ is even.

### This is what I've concluded so far. Can you tell me if I'm wrong, and also advice on how to proceed and how to use the hint?

Comment: Are there any conditions for x and y? Maybe I'm wrong but y=0, x=sqrt(19/3) seems like a fine solution.

Comment: $3x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, or $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$ (after multiplying by $2$).

Comment: I think you should take the hint and consider the equation modulo 5. Here is a further hint? What are the squares modulo 5?

Comment: @cBEiN the only conditions are that they MUST be integers.

Comment: I notice you have $3 \not \equiv 3 \bmod 5$. Can you justify this step?

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the hint you gave yourself.

Modulo $5$ the equation becomes $3x^2\equiv 19\equiv -1 \pmod 5$. Since $2\cdot 3\equiv 1\pmod 5$ we have $x^2\equiv 3\pmod 5$. Do you know any squares that are $3\pmod 5$? You just have to check $0^2,1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2$.

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone None of them work--that is the point

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone See http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Modular_arithmetic/Introduction for what modular arithmetic is about

Comment: Assume that there exist $x$ and $y$ that solve the equation. Then they must solve the congruence mod $5$, which is the $3x^2\equiv -1\pmod 5$ I wrote above. By checking each of the $5$ cases, you see that this cannot have a solution, so a fortiori even the original one cannot have solutions (a solution of the equation in integers gives a solution modulo $5$).

Comment: @Sonner I edited my question, does my work look okay?

Comment: Careful, you have to check that $x^2\equiv 3$ has no solutions, you checked that $3x^2\equiv 3$ has no solutions (in fact it has solutions, which are $x=\pm 1\pmod 5$, for example $48-3=45$ is divisible by $5$ in your list). After you correct this, the proof is perfectly valid.

Comment: You are welcome :)